# Android NullPointerException while invoking virtual method Context.getResource()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-relativelayout, android-context, getresource

I have a task of inflating the view for the object a class called "ToDoItem" using a relative layout for this class named todo_item.xml .I have just started to learn android programming and i cant figure out why i am getting the following error.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

my code looks like this,there are more class specific functions but i have skipped them to make the problem code more visible.

```
    public class ToDoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final List<ToDoItem> mItems = new ArrayList<ToDoItem>();
private final Context mContext;
LayoutInflater mInflater;

private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

public ToDoListAdapter(Context context) {

    mContext = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


}// Create a View for the ToDoItem at specified position
// Remember to check whether convertView holds an already allocated View
// before created a new View.
// Consider using the ViewHolder pattern to make scrolling more efficient
// See: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-    scrolling.html

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // TODO - Get the current ToDoItem
    final ToDoItem toDoItem = (ToDoItem) getItem(position);


    // TODO - Inflate the View for this ToDoItem
    // from todo_item.xml


    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_item,parent,false);

    RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);

    // Fill in specific ToDoItem data
    // Remember that the data that goes in this View
    // corresponds to the user interface elements defined
    // in the layout file

    // TODO - Display Title in TextView
    final TextView titleView = new TextView(null);
    titleView.setText(toDoItem.getTitle());
```

Comment: You should post a complete stack trace from logcat so we can see which line has the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your getView

```
convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_item, parent, false);
```

No need for `mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)`